# Unable to install xgboost Python 3 Mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos, xgboost

I am facing issues while installing xgboost on MacOS 10.10.5. I am using Python 3.6.3. I already tried  `pip install xgboost` but received following error:

```
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/tz/42d7kx0j74jf6j2qqczg6cqm0000gn/T/pip-build-58t0kofo/xgboost/
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the problem was initially but I found a workaround to my problem. Following line works like a charm! However, You need package manager Anaconda.

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
```